# Mongoid eager loading with embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, mongoid, eager-loading

Some of my classes :

```
class User
  embeds_many :notifications
  field :first_name
  field :last_name

  def name{ "#{first_name} #{last_name}" }

class Notification
  embedded_in :user
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", inverse_of: nil
```

Now in my views, I implemented a small mailbox system for notifications. However, it's currently hitting N+1 times the database :

```
<% current_user.notifications.sort{...}.each do |notif|%>
    ...
    <%= notif.sender.name if notif.sender %>
```

The problem here is the `notif.sender.name` which causes `N` hits on the database. Can I somehow preload/eager load this ? Something like  `current_user.notifications.includes(:sender)` (but which would work :D)

I currently only need the sender name.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're half out of luck here. Mongoid has an error message like:

> Eager loading in Mongoid only supports providing arguments to M.includes that are the names of relations on the M model, and only supports one level of eager loading. (ie, eager loading associations not on the M but one step away via another relation is not allowed).

Note the last parenthesized sentence in particular:

> eager loading associations not on the M but one step away via another relation is not allowed

Embedding is a relation but you want to apply `includes` to the embedded relation and that's one step too far for Mongoid.

The [fine manual](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria:includes) does say that:

> This will work for embedded relations that reference another collection via `belongs_to` as well.

but that means that you'd call `includes` on the embedded relation rather than what the models are embedded in. In your case, that means that you could eager load the senders for each set of embedded Notifications:

```
current_user.notifications.includes(:sender).sort { ... }
```

That still leaves you with the `N+1` problem that eager loading is supposed to get around but your `N` will be smaller.

If that's still too heavy then you could denormalize the name into each embedded document (i.e. copy it rather than referencing it through the `sender`). Of course, you'd need to maintain the copies if people were allowed to change their names.

Comment: Haha, actually my problem was totally unrelated. I had a weird error "Wrong number of arguments ..." : the working query is `current_user.notifications.includes(:sender).to_a.sort`. The `to_a` is important here !

Comment: @CyrilDD it might perform better if you were to include the sort within your query instead of having ruby sort on a native  array

Answer (score 3):

It's not perfect, but [this article](http://maximomussini.com/posts/mongoid-n+1/) presents a possible solution.

You can load all the senders and use [set_relation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FRelations%2FAccessors%3Aset_relation) to avoid them to be loaded every time.

```
def notifications_with_senders
  sender_ids = notifications.map(:sender_id)
  senders = User.in(id: sender_ids).index_by(&:id)
  notifications.each do |notification|
   notification.set_relation(:sender, senders[notification.sender_id])
  end
end
```

Would be great to have that as a `Relation` method (like `includes` of Rails Active Record)